# Generate all possible binary matrix as string or generate all possible matrix

Tags: c#, algorithm, matrix, matrix-multiplication

I have 12*3 matrix as below

```
matrix = 0- [0,0,0]
         1- [0,0,0]
         2- [0,0,0]
            .......
        11- [0,0,0]
```

> Each row must have only ***one*** selection as value ***1***

```
matrix = 0- [1,0,0]
         1- [1,0,0]
         2- [1,0,0]
            .......
        11- [1,0,0]
```

My answer array in this case is

```
Ans = {1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,....,1,0,0}
```

I want to generate all answers, like this:

```
Ans = {1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,....,1,0,0}
Ans = {0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,....,1,0,0}
Ans = {0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,....,1,0,0}
Ans = {1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,....,1,0,0}
```

Could you please help me to select best algorithm.

Edit: preferable language is C#

Comment: count from 0 to 3^12 - 1 in base 3. Each such number is easily seen to encode a unique solution.

Comment: @JohnColeman how I convert this base 3 number to unique solution?

Comment: The twelve rows correspond to the 12 places for such numbers. When a digit in a given place is 0, select the first column in that row. When it is a 1, select the second column, etc.

Comment: Asking somebody else to do your homework for you doesn't teach you anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution in c# that write all the answers in a file with the format that you asked.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;

namespace DozeFilastres
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<string> lines = new List<string>();
            int[] finarr = new int[]{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
            int aux=0;


            while(finarr[11]!=3)
            {
                finarr[0]=aux;
                lines.Add(printarr(finarr));
                aux++;
                if(aux==3)
                {
                    aux=0;
                    finarr[0]++;
                    for(int idx=0;idx<11;idx++)
                    {
                        if(finarr[idx]==3)
                        {
                            finarr[idx]=0;
                            finarr[idx+1]++;
                        }
                    }
                }

            }

            File.WriteAllLines("fichero.txt",lines.ToArray());
        }

        static string printarr(int[] arr)
        {
            string all="Ans = {";
            for(int idx=0;idx<12;idx++)
            {
                if(idx!=0)
                    all+=",";

                switch(arr[idx])
                {
                case 0:
                    all+="1,0,0";
                    break;
                case 1:
                    all+="0,1,0";
                    break;
                case 2:
                    all+="0,0,1";
                    break;
                }

            }
            all+="}";

            return all;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can think of each such an array as coding a number in base 3 in the range 0 to 3^12 - 1. The following Python script (with comments suggesting how to convert to C# -- a language I don't use) shows how you can go from such a number to the array:

```
def decode(n):
     A = [0]*36 #initialize array of 36 zeros
     for i in range(0,12): #for(int i = 0; i < 12; i++) in C#
          r = n % 3
          n = n // 3 #integer division, just use / in C# if n is an int
          A[3*i+r] = 1
     return A

#test:
n = 1*3**0 + 2*3**1 + 1*3**2 + 2*3**3 + 1*3**5
A = decode(n)
print(A)
```

Output:

```
[0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]
```

Note that the 1 is in the second position in the first group of 3, the third position in the second group of 3, the second position in the next, the fist position in the fourth, the third position in the fifth, and then in the first position in the remaining blocks.

Comment: Thank you but I need answer array not matrix, Also in c#

Comment: @MasterProgrammer I tweaked to an array, but didn't use c#. The idea is almost trivial and easy enough to implement in any language. It is somewhat inconsistent of you to ask a question about algorithm design and then after the fact throw in a language constraint. Stack Overflow isn't a coding service.

Comment: @JohnColeman he wants all the combinations possible.
The output needs to be 3^12 lines.

Comment: @BlazeChill once you have a function to decode an integer into a unique array of that form it is really and truly trivial to use that function in a loop. Stack Overflow isn't a coding service. If OP wants to write the output to a file, OP can write the output to a file.

Answer (score 0):

To make a full solution I used c++:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void printarr(int arr[]);
FILE *fileptr;
FILE **file;
int main()
{
    int finarr[12] = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
    int aux=0;
    file=&fileptr;
    fopen_s(file,"fichero.txt","w");

    while(finarr[11]!=3)
    {
        finarr[0]=aux;
        printarr(finarr);
        aux++;
        if(aux==3)
        {
            aux=0;
            finarr[0]++;
            for(int idx=0;idx<11;idx++)
            {
                if(finarr[idx]==3)
                {
                    finarr[idx]=0;
                    finarr[idx+1]++;
                }
            }
        }

    }

    printarr(finarr);

    return 0;
}

void printarr(int arr[])
{
    if(arr[11]==3)
        return;
    fprintf(fileptr,"Ans = {");
    for(int idx=0;idx<12;idx++)
    {
        if(idx!=0)
            fprintf(fileptr,",");

        switch(arr[idx])
        {
        case 0:
            fprintf(fileptr,"1,0,0");
            break;
        case 1:
            fprintf(fileptr,"0,1,0");
            break;
        case 2:
            fprintf(fileptr,"0,0,1");
            break;
        }

    }
    fprintf(fileptr,"}\n");
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Could you please write in c# ?

Comment: @MasterProgrammer in fact, i can.